# compareTo(E) generics

Tags: java, generics, compareto

Hi i have a problem with generics. I need to make the method "max" generic so that it can be used on different kinds of collections.

But I'm getting an error that it cannot compare to E

```
public static <E> E max(List<E> list) {
    Iterator<E> iterator = list.iterator();
    E maximum = iterator.next();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        E x = iterator.next();
        if (maximum.compareTo(x) < 0) {
            maximum = x;
        }
    }
    return maximum;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must require `E` to implement `Comparable<E>`:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E max(List<E> list) {
    Iterator<E> iterator = list.iterator();
    E maximum = iterator.next();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        E x = iterator.next();
        if (maximum.compareTo(x) < 0) {
            maximum = x;
        }
    }
    return maximum;
}
```

This lets the compiler know that only `List`s of elements that implement `Comparable` may be passed to that method.

Comment: `(List<E> list)` -> `(Iterable<E> list)` for maximum flexibility?

Comment: to be more general, use `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`

Answer (score 1):

@Eran answer could be good enough for your use-case but a more flexible signature for the max function would be

```
static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> E max(List<E> list)
```

So a `Circle` class that extends `Shape` class which implements `Comparable<Shape>` would work too.